# How do I move items from my cart and to an orders list?

Tags: javascript, shopping-cart

I am new to coding and would love your help and/or guidance on my shopping cart.  How do I get items in my shopping cart to move to "My Current List" when pressing "Purchase".  I am able to figure out how to make them from the items section to my cart, but not from the cart to my orders list.

For the purchaseclicked function, when clicking on Purchase I would like...

1. Items in the Cart to be cleared out.
2. Items in the Cart to be added to section below..."The Current List" section.

I would love you help on the Javascript end.

```
function purchaseClicked() {

alert('Thank you for your purchase')
var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
while (cartItems.hasChildNodes()) {
cartItems.removeChild(cartItems.firstChild)

}

updateCartTotal()
updateTotalRemaining()

var button = event.target
var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText
var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText
addItemToList(title, price)
```

}

```
function addItemToList(title, price) {
     var listRow = document.createElement('div')
     listRow.classList.add('list-row')
    listRow.innerText = title
    var listItems = document.getElementsByClassName('list-items')[0]
    var listItemNames = listItems.getElementsByClassName('list-item-title')
   
    for (var i = 0; i < listItemNames.length; i++) {
        if (listItemNames[i].innerText == title) {
        alert('This item is already added to the list')
        return
    }
}

var listRowContents = `
    <div class="list-item list-column">
       
        <span class="list-item-title">${title}</span>
    </div>
    <span class="list-price list-column">${price}</span>
    <div class="list-quantity list-column">
        <input class="list-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
    </div>`

listRow.innerHTML = listRowContents
listItems.append(listRow)
listRow.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
listRow.getElementsByClassName('list-quantity-input')[0].addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
```

}